# How to bind a gridcontrol to a list of expando objects with AutoGenerateColumns set to true?

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, expandoobject

I m trying to autogenerate columns in a gridcontrol when they are bound to a list of expando objects. I was expecting each of the individual field i set in the expando object would turn up as column in the grid and the property value as the cell value in the grid but I get only 2 columns(Key ,Value) on the grid because of the underlying IDictionary that expando objects use.

I know this functionality can be accomplished using a data table and by varying the columns but i thought of going the dynamic route.

Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I wonder if it depends on the (3rd party?) grid to specifically handle ExpandoObject?

Comment: I've taken the approach of adding the columns to the grid in the code behind. They come from a user-defined list in our case.